# Can not load url helper in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, helper

I tried to load `base_url()` in controller, but codeigniter does not load the `helper('url')`. I also call helper from `autoload` and the constructor both in the hook, but it's still not working and showing an error "Trying to get property of non-object".

Any idea how can I redirect?

My code:

```
if ( !defined( 'BASEPATH' ) ) exit( 'No direct script access allowed' );

class Auth_hook {

    protected $CI;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index(){
      redirect(base_url('auth/login'));

      print_r("hello!!");
      if(isset($_SESSION['name']) == 'TRUE'){
        redirect(base_url('auth/admin'));
      }
      else {
        redirect(base_url('auth/login'));
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Load it just once. I suggest that removing it from hook and put it in `FCPATH.'config/autoload.php'` file only. And in case if you are not using pre system hook. Otherwise, `APPPATH.'config/autoload.php'` is loaded first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
class Auth_hook {

  protected $CI;

  public function __construct() {
      $this->CI =& get_instance();
  }

  public function index(){
    // can communicate back with CI by using $this->CI
    $this->CI->load->helper('url');

    redirect(base_url('auth/login'));

    print_r("hello!!");
    if(isset($_SESSION['name']) == 'TRUE'){
      redirect(base_url('auth/admin'));
    }
    else {
      redirect(base_url('auth/login'));
    }
  }
}
```